# Comparing two things in one sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, terminology

We have three shapes in my study. We called them trees.  The class of Tree 1 is larger than the class of tree 2 and tree 3. Also, the shape of tree 1 contains the shapes of both tree 2 and tree 3. I would like to compare them and show that tree 2 and tree 3 are contained in tree 1. Here is my try:

> *The class of tree 1 is larger than the one of the second and third tree, containing both of them.*

or

> *The class of tree 1 is larger than the one of the second and third tree and contains both of them*.

How can I compare two things and mention the ability of one of them in one sentence?

Comment: It might help to know what the trees look like. Do they look like (a) [these trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo9kE.png)? Or (b) [these trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E9df.png)?

Comment: Consider *Class 2 and Class 3 are **subclasses** of Class 1.* More generally, perhaps, *X and Y are **subsets / subcategories / subtypes** of Z.* But with the "indirection" of something like *The class of Z is broader than the subclasses of X and Y*, all you're really saying is "Z is not very precisely defined, but it shares at least *some* characteristics with X and Y".

Comment: Most speakers won't know what you mean by "the class of a tree" or how a class can have dimension or number. They would be confused by "larger".

Comment: @J.R. I meant (b).

Answer (score 0):

A is larger than both B and C.

The  x of A is larger than that of both B and C.

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following samples help you:

> The class of tree 1 is larger than the other ones that named tree 2
>   and tree 3, which are as a subclass of it.
>
> The class of tree 1 is larger than the classes of tree 2 and tree 3,
>   which are as a subclass of it.